# how i can make action bar fixed in android studio tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-activity, action, tabbed

I have a small problem with android - specifically in Tabbed activity tabs.
When I move the action bar up, it moves up and down. I need to make this action bar Fixed, like any another activity.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.herosaif.jadapp.Main2Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the following line from your Toolbar:

```
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: thanks bro , you are saved my day :)  i have another question about how i can add new Section in The Bar ? Tabbed Activity Default bar number is 3 section only , how i can add four section ?

Comment: @HeroGuevara Inside your Activity there's a class called **"SectionsPagerAdapter"**. Within this class there should be a method called **"getCount()"**. There you just need to return the amount of the needed Tabs.

Comment: i respect you man , thanks you , funny Question if you are allow me to ask you , from 10 ? how many give me in English Languge ?